# Apply a Draggable Container Above Another Absolutely Positioned Element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which contains and IFRAME that points to other pages.  The IFRAMES parent will contain the Search Control that changes the IFRAME's URL. The IFRAME should always display max-screen, but the SEARCH CONTROL needs to lay atop the IFRAME results.

I basically want it "always on top"

How can I achieve this?

**FOR INSTANCE, THE HTML LOOKS LIKE:**
I've tried messing with the z-index...with no success.

```
<style>
    iframe { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 90; }
    .search { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100px; width: 100px; z-index: 100;}
</style>

<div class="search>
    This Is My SEARCH CONTROLS CONTAINER
</div>
<div class="container">
    <iframe src="~/tours/_default/index.html" allowfullscreen align="center" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing double-quote after `"search`. Add that in and see if that helps. I just tested this locally and it works for me when adding in the missing ".

Comment: @PrisonerZERO Not a problem - done that myself and spent hours searching Javascript only to find it was a markup issue!! :)